# How can I find a list of all North American ETF's including symbols?

Tags: etf, yahoo-finance

I was hoping to find a list of all North American ETF's. Unfortunately https://www.quandl.com/resources/useful-lists just returns an error when the corresponding list is clicked. I'd really prefer excel or CSV, something where I can easily pull just the symbols.

Does anyone have an alternate source for this information? I had thought to find it easily on yahoo finance, but my google-fu seems to be failing.

Comment: You might want to add some reasons why this is useful information with respect to Personal Finance.

Comment: @Lark You might get better answers on the quant finance SE.

Comment: What is a "North American ETF"? Would it be an ETF listed, say, anywhere in the world that invests in securities from North America, or would it be an ETF listed on a North American exchange that invests in securities from anywhere in the world?

Comment: @rhaskett, that one seems terribly intimidating and WAY over my head, but it might come to that.

Comment: The first task of any quant is gathering good data. Analyzing a list of all the >1353 etfs domiciled in the US that focus on NA stocks (source Bloomberg) will require some persistence.

Comment: I'll likely end up tossing most of them based on metrics (beta, P/E, etc). But I can do that programatically. I needed the data first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use www.etfdb.com and search on geography.